# How to capture console.log from external sources?

Tags: javascript, iframe, console.log

I understand how to modify the console.log function to intercept the logs and push it into an array. However this does not seem to work for all console log. In my html, I've loaded a html webapp (`\creative\300x600 with video\index.html`) that also does a `console.log("click detected")` that I can see in my chrome dev tools, but is not captured by console. ogs (The second script in the code example). I suspect that because this is an external file being loaded in, I cannot intercept it.

Is there a solution to get all console.log from any source and save it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>

//add index.html to div on click

function load_home() {
    console.log("Loaded");
    document.getElementById("content").src='creative\\300x600 with video\\index.html';

}
window.addEventListener("click",load_home);
</script>
<script>

//modify console.log

console.defaultLog = console.log.bind(console);
console.logs = [];
console.log = function() {
    console.defaultLog.apply(console, arguments);
    console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
};
    </script>
</head>
<html>
<iframe id="content" style="width: 300px; height:600px; background-color:blue"  ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Tried making it on a div rather than in an iframe, same issue of not being able to record the console.log of the external html. Only     `console.log("loaded")` from the load_home function gets logged.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<script>
function load_home() {
    console.log("Loaded");
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="creative\\300x600 with video\\index.html" ></object>';


}
window.addEventListener("click",load_home);
</script>
<script>
console.defaultLog = console.log.bind(console);
console.logs = [];
console.log = function() {
    console.defaultLog.apply(console, arguments);
    console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
};
    </script>
</head>
<html>


<div id="content" style="width: 300px; height:600px; z-index:-1;" ,"onclick=load_home();" </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is because of that `iframe`. `iframe`s have a different `window` object, independent from the parent's `window` object. This means whatever modifications you did to the parent's `window.console` will not affect the iframe's `window.console`.

You could get the frame's `window` object via [`contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) and modify its `console`. But you'd have to do this for each present *and future* `iframe`. Additionally, you cannot access the `contentWindow` of a iframe rendering a page from another domain.

If you're attempting to capture the logs of all the frames and somehow consolidate them into one big log, a better option is to have that same `console`-altering script on every page you want tracked. Then send all your logs to the server, ordered by timestamp or something. That's pretty much how [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) works.

Comment: I've updated the code in an update to my original question to use a div rather than an iframe but still encounter the same issue. Just to clarify, the external html loads a console log which is visible in chrome dev tools, but not being logged by my modified function. Does this mean I need to access the external html and modify that console.log function instead?

Comment: @kevhol That external page, whether it's loaded in an `<iframe>` or `<object>`, is a totally different document with its own global scope. The only way to get your script to work is to have access to that page (i.e. you have access to code, or is hosted in the same domain).

Comment: The external file is hosted on the same domain. I'm research on how to access that page and change variables in that scope.